# How to use Insert .. select, with conditional vars from insert

Tags: sql, mysql

I have two separate tables both with user id columns `uid`. I want to take a value from all users in one table and insert it into the correct row for the correct user in the other table.

```
INSERT INTO users2 (picture) 
   SELECT pv.value 
   FROM profile_values as pv, users2 as u 
   WHERE pv.uid = u.uid 
   AND pv.fid = 31 
   AND users2.uid=u.uid;
```

But it's not working because i seem not to have access to users2.uid inside of the select statement.

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to access your `u` alias for `users2` fine.  Direct access to `users2` isn't possible because you're `INSERT`ing into it, so the row doesn't actually exist yet.  Do you want to do an `insert` or `update`?

Comment: Replaced with `UPDATE users2, profile_values 
SET users2.picture = profile_values.value
WHERE profile_values.uid = users2.uid 
AND profile_values.fid = 31;`